# Can someone help me make sense of this equation?

Tags: geometry, voronoi-diagram

I've been studying Voronoi diagrams and came upon this definition of a Voronoi region, $$V\left ( p_{i} \right )=\left \{ \vec{x}\mid \left |  \right |\vec{x}-\vec{x_{i}}\left |  \right |\leq\left |  \right | \vec{x}-\vec{x_{j}} \left |  \right |\forall j\ni i\neq j \right \}$$ in which $\vec{x_{i}}$ is the generator corresponding to the $V\left ( p_{i} \right )$ region,  $\vec{x_{j}}$ is the generator corresponding to another region, and $\vec{x}$ is any point which isn't part of the set of the Voronoi diagram's generators. The inequality part I kind of get it, but what's around it confuses me.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.)

Comment: The author is using $ni$ to mean "such that", so the part of the formula after the inequality says "for all $j$ such that $i\neq j$. (It would be equivalent to say simply "for all $i$", since the inequality holds trivially when $j=i$.)